# load UIView from left animation on UIButton click

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewanimation

I am having one UIButton on navigation bar as right bar button item.
I want to show one view when I click on the UIButton,
and that view should appear animating from right to left and stops to perform some operations for user.
when user is done from his work on the view he will click on same button and view will hide animating from right to left.

I tried to load view normally I get succeed in it,
when I apply animation 
view animates from right to left and disappears.
I am new to this animation scenario.
So can anyone please guide me to animate view and show hide action on same button.

Here is the code that I tried,

```
-(IBAction)showView :(id)sender
{
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];
    UIView *quizInfoViewObj;
    quizInfoViewObj = [[UIView alloc]init];
    quizInfoViewObj.frame = CGRectMake(70, 0, 250, 480);
    quizInfoViewObj.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(pushAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    quizInfoViewObj.center = self.view.center;
    quizInfoViewObj.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x - CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), self.view.center.y);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self.view addSubview:quizInfoViewObj];
}
```

here how I want...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code might help you.

```
   -(IBAction)showView :(id)sender
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

        if ([button isSelected] == NO) {

        CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];
        // UIView *quizInfoViewObj; // use this line in .h file variables declaration

        quizInfoViewObj = [[UIView alloc]init];
        quizInfoViewObj.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width, 0, 250, 480);

        quizInfoViewObj.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

        [self.view addSubview:quizInfoViewObj];

        [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: NULL];

        quizInfoViewObj.frame = CGRectMake(70, 0, 250, 480);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

       }
       else {

        [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(pushAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
// In pushAnimationDidStop:finished:context method remove quizInfoViewObj from superview

        quizInfoViewObj.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width, 0, 250, 480);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
       }
    [button setSelected: ![button isSelected]];
}
```

Comment: Hi Mrunal,Thanks.
It worked.
and I hide the view in pushAnimationDidStop method
Thanks

Comment: In the if block you are adding a new subview so I would suggest you to remove it in else block. Otherwise each time it will alloc-init a new view. Or else alloc-init this view in viewDidLoad and use setHidden method in if-else block.

Comment: Ok
I will alloc the view once at the time of loading main view, but addition and remove of view will be done as per suggested by you